# Manage JFrame Instances

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In my project I've one instance of `jframe1` and two instance of `jframe2`. Then I want to update from `jframe1` `txt2` component of first instance of `jframe2`. But when I invoke `perfomaction()` method it was to update the second instance of `jframe2`.

```
public class Jframe1 extends Jframe {
    public jframe1() {
    Performedaction() {
       jframe2.txt2.setText("do it");
    }
}

public class jframe2 extends Jframe {
    public static JtextFiedl txt2;
    public jframe2() {
}
```

Comment: `static` is not your friend. Each instance of `jframe2` should have it's own instance of `txt2`, not a shared instance

Comment: how to identify witch instance of JFrame 2 first or second if invoke performedaction two time

Comment: Keep and reference to both

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). **Not** some code you typed out quickly that is 'something like' the problem, but code that has correctly capitalized class names and would compile as copied.  2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 4) Don't extend components/windows when you can use a standard instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.. The example uses two `JFrame` window's and on clicking a button in one jframe, the second one's `JLabel` is updated. The example uses a `JLabel` instead of `JTextField`.

The mechanism uses `java.util.Observer` interface and `Observable` class to update from one window to the other one.

The example's code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TwoFramesExample {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TwoFramesExample().start();
            }
        });
    }
    private void start() {
        Frame1 f1 = new Frame1();
        new Frame2(f1);
    }
}

class Frame1 implements Observer {
    private JLabel label;
    @Override // Observer interface's implemented method
    public void update(Observable o, Object data) { 
        label.setText((String) data); // displays new text in JLabel
    }
    Frame1() {  
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Frame-1");
        f1.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));        
        label = new JLabel("Click button in frame-2...");
        label.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));  
        f1.add(label);
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setSize(350, 150);
        f1.setLocation(200, 200);
        f1.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Frame2 {
    private int clicks;
    Frame2(Frame1 f1) {
        // Create Observable and add Observer       
        final MessageObservable observable = new MessageObservable();
        observable.addObserver(f1);
        // Display frame
        JFrame f2 = new JFrame("Frame-2");      
        JButton button = new JButton("Press me");
        button.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String data = "button clicks in frame-2: [" + ++clicks + "]";
                observable.changeData(data);
            }
        });     
        f2.add(button);
        f2.setSize(250, 150);
        f2.setLocation(600, 200);
        f2.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MessageObservable extends Observable {
    MessageObservable() {   
        super();
    }
    void changeData(Object data) {
        // the two methods of Observable class
        setChanged(); 
        notifyObservers(data);
    }
}
```